# なった versus なってきた

Tags: word-choice, grammar

My friend recently said to me:

> 眠くなってきた　【ねむくなってきた】

Which, I think means "I became sleepy".

But it seems to me that it is the same as saying:

> 眠くなった

How does the addition of `きた` change this phrase?

Comment: I'm not really qualified to answer as I'm sort of going on "feeling", but to me, 眠くなった sounds very sudden. "I got sleepy" (suddenly). A very quick change. However, 眠くなってきた sounds much more like, "I've gotten sleepy" (over a period of time up until now). A much more gradual change. However, I could be incorrect...

Comment: Also, I think you're missing a っ in なった。

Comment: @phirru: Thanks for catching that. Corrected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

phirru's comment is almost correct: Addition of `くる` in this case means that it happened gradually. It also means that it might not yet be complete. However, the one without `くる` does not necessarily mean suddenly. It just does not mention the process. It may or may not have happened suddenly. `いく` can be used with similar meaning, but the perspective will be different.

> 眠くなってきた
> 'I am becoming sleepy.'
> 'I have (gradually) become sleepy.'
>
> 眠くなった
> 'I became sleepy.'

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! Very easy to understand, +1.